# Testing backbone model extend from another model with mocha

Tags: testing, backbone.js, model, mocha.js

When I run my tests (I am using `Mocha, Chai and Sinon`) for a backbone model which extends from another backbone model, I get an error:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Model._entity')`

I thought that by instantiating `Model._entity` that this error would go away, but it doesn't. Should I be using a stub instead?

I've searched the web for an answer but all the examples are for models that extend directly from `Backbone` and not another model.

What do I need to do to avoid this error?

My test code:

```
describe("Model.address", function () {

    beforeEach(function () {

        // build up a fake server
        this.server = sinon.fakeServer.create();

        this.server.autoRespond = true;

        this.parentModel = new Model._entity();

        this.Model_address = new Model.Address();
    });


    afterEach(function () {

        // delete fake server
        this.server.restore();
    });

    describe("Defaults", function () {

        // test defaults
        it("has default values", function () {
            // create empty model
            var model = this.Model_address;

            // expect model to be truthy
            expect(model).to.be.ok;


        });

    });
});
```

Model._entity:

```
Model._entity = Backbone.Model.extend({

    initialize: function(options) {

        //If options passed with created and/or modified values, set the corresponding model attributes
        if (options && options.created && typeof options.created === 'string') {
            this.set('created', new Date(options.created));
        }
        if (options && options.modified && typeof options.modified === 'string') {
            this.set('modified', new Date(options.modified));
        }
    },

    defaults: function() {
        return {
            created: new Date(),
            modified: new Date()
        };
    }
});
```

Model.Address:

```
Model.Address = Model._entity.extend({
    invalidField: false,

    defaults: function () {
        var superDefs;  //defaults 'inherited' from parent model  

        superDefs = Model._entity.prototype.defaults.apply(this, arguments);
        return _.defaults(superDefs, {
            firstLine: '',
            secondLine: '',
            postalCode: '',     //TODO: move down
            houseNumber: '',    //TODO: move up 
            city: '',
            country: 'uk'
        });
    },

    urlRoot: function () {
        return '/checkout/address';
    },

    validate: function (attributes, options) {
        var attr;

        for (attr in attributes) {
            if (attributes[attr] === '') {
                this.invalidField = true;
                return 'Blank field';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us what your Address Model and Entity Model look like?

Comment: @garethdn I've just updated the question

Comment: You shouldn't need to instantiate your entity model before you instantiate your Address model. However, the entity model should be loaded on the page before you try to instantiate the Address model, just like Backbone is loaded on the page before you instantiate any model.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. Indeed I was loading the Address model just before the Entity model. Such a simple oversight!

Comment: @garethdn How would you write the test to check the return value of the `validate` method?
I have come up with 
`expect("Blank field").to.satisfy(this.Model_address.validate);` but get and error `AssertionError: expected 'Blank field' to satisfy [Function]`

Comment: `expect("Blank field").to.satisfy(this.Model_address.validate())`